# Outlook accepting meetings on behalf of?

Tags: outlook-2007

A couple of my users are having a problem where they will accept a meeting request, but the accept notice sent to the meeting coordinator says, "Accepted on behalf of X user by Y user." I have triple checked the settings for the permissions, and none of the people accepting on behalf of have access. (Not that they are actually doing the accepting anyways.)

We are currently using an Exchage2003 server with Office 2007. OS wise it's XP pro SP3.

Comment: Are they accepting with an iPhone?

Comment: For now I am going to say no since most of them do not have iPhones.

Comment: Ok. As an FYI, I've noticed that when I accept a meeting request on my iPhone it will accept from me on behalf of some other user.

Comment: Ugh, it turns out that they do have iPhones. I knew one had an iphone, but apparently they both do. (Love how people share things with their help desk. :P)

Thanks for help everyone. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: How are the meeting requests sent out?  actual steps.

Comment: And the steps for accepting the requests

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose those two users are using any similar odd Outlook add-ins?  I know that SP3 fixed some odd Outlook invite bugs, makes me wonder if a wire got crossed with previously written addins.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither are using any kind of plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Are the people accepting direct recipients of the original invite?  This will happen if someone is forwarded a meeting request by someone who was directly invited.

Comment: They are direct recipients of the original invite.

Comment: Ok, shoots that theory...

Answer (score 0):

check the delegate tab (tools --> options --> delegates).  I have had users with the same problem and I removed anyone that showed as a delegate and that resolved the issue

Comment: None of the users have any delegates